# Why can't the generic interface in TS infer the type correctly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Once "extends `Explicit_value`" is used in generic interfaces, TS's type system will become "stupid", even if the code is "100% correct".

```js
function fn<T extends "a" | "b">(param: T): T {
    if (param === "a") return "a"/* <-- error
Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '"a"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"a" | "b"'.
 */
    else return "b"/* <-- error
Type '"b"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '"b"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"a" | "b"'.
 */
}

//that's ok:
function fn2<T extends string>(param: T): T {
    return param
}

//even this:
function fn3<T extends "a">(): T {
    return "a"/* <-- error
Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '"a"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"a"'.
 */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say it is stupid. It just safe.
C0nsider this example:

```js
function fn3<T extends "a">(): T {
  return "a" // error

}

const result = fn3<'a' & { tag: 2 }>().tag // 2
```

It means that `T` extends `a` but not equal 'a'.
In above example, `result` is `2` but in runtime it equals `undefined`.

This is why TS gives you an error. Generic parameter should be binded with runtime value. Just like you did in your second example.

Let's take a look on your first example:

```js
function fn<T extends "a" | "b">(param: T): T {
  if (param === "a") return "a"
  else return "b"

}
```

The error:

> '"a"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"a" | "b"'

Please keep in mind, it does not mean that `T` is always equal to `a` or `b`. `T` can be any subtype of this constraint/union.
For instance, you can use `never` which is the bottom type of type system:

```js
const throwError = () => {
  throw Error('Hello')
}

fn<'a' | 'b'>(throwError())
```

Is there any chance that `fn` will return `a` or `b`? No, it will throw an error. Maybe this is not the best example just wanted to show you the meaning of different subtypes.

Let's call `fn` with different set of subtypes:

```js
declare var a: 'a' & { tag: 'hello' }

const result = fn(a).tag // undefined
```

You might say: Hey, you are not playing by the rules. Type `'a' & { tag: 'hello' }` is unrepresentable in runtime. In fact it is not.  `tag` will always be `undefined` in runtime.
But, we are in a type scope. We can easily create such kind of type.

**SUMMARY**

Please dont treat `extends` as an equal operator. It just means that `T` might be any subtype of defined constraint.

**P.S.** Types are immutable in TypeScript. It means that once you created type `T` with some constraint, you are unable to return same generic parameter `T` with other constraint. I mean, in your first example, return type `T` can't be only `a` or only `b`. It will always be `a | b`

Comment: Thanks.
I never thought about code like `'a' & { tag: 'hello' }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitation in TypeScript's type checking system.  This example can be better understood in the case of `true | false`:

```
function returnSelf<T extends true | false>(param: T): T {
  if (param === true) {
    type CUR_VAL = T; // original `T`, not `true` if it narrowed
    return true;
  } else {
    type CUR_VAL = T; // original `T`, not `false` if it narrowed
    return false;
  }
}
```

If you [open the code in a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsBlVAbYAHgBVFUAPKVMAEwGdEpkRVEAfRYAQzztQD4AFAAcuyLgFsAXImIBKGaQDeAKESIYwRCLGTEAXkONmqOYlXr1UAJ7DWAYQCqAJQD6ANQCCAGQOyA3IgA9EGIcMgwAOYwYDyIAAbE8QA0iGBwUAlMLPEaWjCZscjIcADuqDRqlmgYWMYs-lUAvmS8rBaWNnaITm5evvoBwaHhUTFxiSlpGQncbbmaGoViJeWVlijomEhzfI3qTSpNQA) and hover over the `CUR_VAL` type alias, you will notice that it is still equal to `T`, not the narrowed value.  Therefore, when you try to return the value, it still thinks that `T` is `true | false` which makes it invalid.