# Typescript utilities 'Record' and 'Partial' don't work with a constrained generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, typescript-utility

I need to create a new type based on a constrained generic. The new type should have the same keys as the generic, make them optional and map them to a number.

My first approach was to use `Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>` which for some reason lead to the error `Type [...] is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>'.`.

So I resorted to write the type mapping manually `{ [K in keyof Entity]?: number }` which seems to work.

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export class SomeClass<Entity extends Person> {
  protected getFilter(): void {
    let prio1: { [K in keyof Entity]?: number };
    prio1 = { firstName: 1 };

    // Type '{ firstName: 2; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>'.
    let prio2: Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>;
    prio2 = { firstName: 2 };
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what the difference between those two notations is and why the built-in Typescript utilities don't work?

The code snippet is also available on Typescript playground: [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKihScCmQAZgwWdJBkgvBeAN6KoKARFPGoAHIMyABcoIKolJzMANypbgzFuQVFJaEVigC%20wZAAHgTwZDSwjILCxEiQAMIDggA8AKJh8nignQo8wrRxCZwAfKApaQRsCrAKrsyQqABiFNDhABQAlIU68BSuu2luZ6D7FPAAjIVJUAAbQA0iIvABrSCGCKgWaoeYAXQA-IVOOxENI4qAWpV3l9KH9QABeHbpTK1PKQQq-HGVKppdw0b7wABMhVojgRDGgkwASpAEGRuJMoTC4XNUHh%20OjMXFNps8e8WaySWSMlk6tTQKrcVU2m0gA).

Resources I have used: [Records](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)

---

**Update:**

I tried to break down what Typescript does internally, desugaring `Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>` step by step, using the official type definitions:

```js
/**
 * Make all properties in T optional
 */
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] };

/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = { [P in K]: T };


class SomeClass<Entity extends Person> {
  getFilter(): void {
    let prio1: { [K in keyof Entity]?: number };
    prio1 = { firstName: 1 };

    let p1: Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>;
    let p2: Partial<{ [P in keyof Entity]: number }>;
    let p3: { [P2 in keyof { [P1 in keyof Entity]: number }]?: { [P1 in keyof Entity]: number }[P2] };
    let p4: { [P2 in keyof Entity]?: { [P1 in keyof Entity]: number }[P2] };
    let p5: { [P2 in keyof Entity]?: number };

    p1 = { firstName: 3 }; // error
    p2 = { firstName: 3 }; // error
    p3 = { firstName: 3 }; // error
    p4 = { firstName: 3 }; // error
    p5 = { firstName: 3 }; // works
  }
}
```

Typescript seems to be unable to resolve `{ [P1 in keyof Entity]: number }[P2]` with `P2 in keyof Entity` to `number`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596). It should give you some context.

Treat `Entity` as a subtype of `Person`. It has not only `Person` props but may have some other props.

See this example:

```js
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

type User = {
    premium: true
} & Person
```

`User` is a subtype of `Person`, in other words it extends `Person`.

Let's create user object:

```js
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

type User = {
    premium: true
} & Person

let user: Record<keyof User, number> = {
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 2,
    premium: 3
}
```

So, our `Partial` user may have a lot of states:

```js
// just an alias
type PartiaUser = Partial<Record<keyof User, number>>

let partialUser1: PartiaUser = {}
let partialUser2: PartiaUser = { firstName: 1 }
let partialUser3: PartiaUser = { firstName: 1, lastName: 2, }
let partialUser4: PartiaUser = { lastName: 2, }
let partialUser5: PartiaUser = { lastName: 2, premium: 3, }
```

See `partialUser5` it is an object without `firstName` property.

Let's go back to your example:

```js
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export class SomeClass<Entity extends Person> {
    getFilter(): void {
        let prio1: { [K in keyof Entity]?: number };
        prio1 = { firstName: 1 };

        let prio2: Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>;
        prio2 = { firstName: 2 };
    }
}
```

`prior1` works because in this case `prior1` definitely has optional `firstName` property since `Entity` has all keys of `Person`.

`prior2` is much interesting.

I think the problem is in dynamic nature of javascript. It is only my opinion.

See this example:

```js
type User = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    premium: true
} & string

type IsExtends<T> = T extends Person ? true : false

type Test = IsExtends<User>
```

The problem is that above `User` type still extends `Person`.

```js
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

type User = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    premium: true
} & string

export class SomeClass<Entity extends Person> {
    getFilter(): void {
        let prio1: { [K in keyof Entity]?: number };
        prio1 = { firstName: 1 };

        let prio2: Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>;
        prio2 = { firstName: 2 };
    }
}
const result = new SomeClass<User>() // no error
```

In fact, `User` is a  string with some static properties.

It is representable in type system but unpresentable in runtime.

Let's test it on small example:

```js
type PartialUser = Partial<Record<keyof User, number>>
declare var partialUser: PartialUser

partialUser = { firstName: 2 } // error
```

In this case, problem is in `toString` method. Please take a look how `toString` is implemented in `string` primitive:

```js
// toString: () => string;
type ToString = Pick<{
    [Prop in keyof string]: string[Prop]
}, 'toString'>
```

As you might have noticed,`toString` is a function. I mean value of `toString` is a function. **But**, `Record<keyof User, number>` expects every value to be a `number`.

Let's take a look again on our example:

```js
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

type User = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    premium: true;
    toString: number;
}

export class SomeClass<Entity extends Person> {
    getFilter(): void {
        let prio1: { [K in keyof Entity]?: number };
        prio1 = { firstName: 1 };
        // added User for experimenting with prio2 = { firstName: 2, toString: 42 }
        let prio2: Partial<Record<keyof User, number>>;
        prio2 = { firstName: 2 };
    }
}
const result = new SomeClass<User>() // no error
```

I have added explicitly `toString` property for the sake of clarity.

`prio1 = { firstName: 1 }` - works because we have created new type where each value is `number`.

Because we have overwritten built in method, typescript claims that this method is not compatible with default `toString`.

Try to use `prio2 = { firstName: 2, toString: 42 }`. You will see that it will fix the error.

By the default, TS expects every object to have `toString` as a method and it is expected behavior. But if you overwrite it - it will make TS unhappy

I hope it is clear now why do you have an error.

`extends` - does not mean - `equal`

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/Nd4gkN)

[Related github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28839#issuecomment-446342782)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I followed along with your examples and agree to your analysis regarding `toString`: the type `() => string` is not compatible with `number`.
But I'm not sure if this is the actual root cause. In fact the last code example only works for `prio1` because its type is based on `keyof Entity` instead of `keyof User`. If it were based on `User` it will also result in `Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: @Elias Rabl I'm happy my answer was clear enough. It is also a progress for me :D

Comment: please see my updated comment. I've also updated the last part of my original question to include my attempts of desugaring the TS definitions for `Partial` and `Record`.

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: In my opinion `{ [K in keyof Entity]?: number }` should be equal to `Partial<Record<keyof Entity, number>>` as the latter one is simply syntactic sugar to achive the same. Manually breaking down the second statement using the internal type definitions for `Partial` and `Filter` from Typescript, I end up exactly with the expected type. But for some reason Typescript does not resolve it the same way. It should be able to simplify `{ [P1 in keyof Entity]: number }[P2]` with `P2 in keyof Entity` to `number`, since all fields in Entity are mapped to number and P2 represents all keys of Entity.