# Problem with Typescript interface and dynamic properties using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, dynamic-properties

This function

```
function abc<K extends keyof any>(
  param: K,
) {
  const z: { [p in K]: string } = {
    [param]: 'abc',
  };
}
```

gives the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [p in K]: string; }'.
```

Isn't something like this possible in typescript?
I'm using Typescript 4.3.5

Thanks

José

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). *"Isn't something like this possible in typescript?"* Something like what? It's not really clear from the code or question text/title what specifically you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because TS is unsure about `K` generic parameter. It is a black box for compiler.

See this example:

```js
function abc<K extends PropertyKey>(
    param: K,
) {
    const z: { [p in K]: string } = {
        [param]: 'abc',
    };

    return z
}

const result2 = abc<42 | 'prop' | symbol>('prop')
```

`keyof any` is the same as built in `PropertyKey`. Also, `PropertyKey` is a union type, hence `K` might be a union as well.

Consider above example. `K` is a `42 | 'prop' | symbol` which is perfectly valid type and meets the requirement.

Because `K` is a union, in theory `z` should be `{ [p in 42 | 'prop' | symbol]: string }`, right? So we should get an object with three properties? But you have provided only one.

Again, because `K` is a black box for TS compiler it is unsafe to make any assumptions.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190069/typescript-utilities-record-and-partial-dont-work-with-a-constrained-generi/69205810?noredirect=1#comment122566030_69205810)

Comment: I understand what you say, thank you.
But I thought `param: K` could limit `K` to only one possibility. The problem might be that that constraint is not in the realm of static typing.