# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'U[T]'

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why typescript is giving me this error:

[image: Type 'boolean is not assignable to type 'U[T]']

This is the relevant code:

```js
  getFeaturesFromMembership$<T extends keyof MembershipFeatures,
    U extends Record<T, boolean>>(membership$: Observable<Membership>,
                                  featureKeys: T[],
                                  isPreview$: Observable<boolean> = of(false)
  ): Observable<U> {
    return combineLatest([membership$, isPreview$])
      .pipe(
        map(([membership, isPreview]) => {
          const features: U = {} as U;

          for (const key of featureKeys) {
            features[key] = false; // <- error here
          }

          if (!membership || isPreview) {
            Object.keys(features).forEach(key => features[key] = true);
            return features;
          }

          Object.keys(features).forEach(key => features[key] = key in membership.features ? membership.features[key] : true);

          return features;
        })
      );
  }
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-IDWEAngIwBcyAzmFKAOYDcuBRpATFbfSM7gF9cuGAFcQCMMAD2IZAwhgAPABVkEAB6QQAE2rsS0mGgA0yAKrqtEXfoBKEBNKg7VZgEbTpAGwhwQAHwBABTEJFQqAJRUltg4rAROILTIGjHIALyYAshw+uYseAQaANphALqZyHSiEIUJ+FCKolByGvU4QvE4SSlN+lkKYMEA5GFkI5GFQA)

Comment: pls provide reproducible example

Comment: I added a playground example link

Comment: It does not work that way. Regarding `U` please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596 . Is it helpful ?

Comment: From the other hand, mutation of object can lead you to another type of errors. See my article regarding mutations in TS https://catchts.com/mutations

Comment: See this example tsplay.dev/mx51GW  .  `U` might be any allowed subtype of `Record<T, boolean>`

Comment: it makes sense, thanks. I rewrote it a little: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-IDWEAngIwBcyAzmFKAOYDcuBRpATFbfSM6wWIkAzNzqMWOAL65cMAK4gEYYAHsQyBhDAAeACrIIAD0ggAJtXYlVMNAD4AFEOpU9AbQC6ASioAlCAiqUGY6YCQADhA2VtRuIPIAtgBG0B4ANMhJqqoANhBwIHaYsjgC+IEgtMhGyAC8yADySQBWAWAAdDBQqgkAouD0ENROpNTtCXDhIyR1RW5CGXTyEN5eyHCW-oHBoRFRts5xiSlQ6ZnZeQV2kmXIUNryUBpGN9IlFVX3lvVaYA5uAHIhGQARkgaRhADvJIvu1gUxkAB6RHIVSEXCwoQcBHI5BmVRDEAAsCGIzAWhUNEYoZwiE4lFooA, and now it works. However, I don't like the fact that I'm repeating the return type. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @BartvandenBurg I just posted an answer

Comment: @Bart van den Burg, I dont think you need Object.entries in your example. I have replaced `entries` and `map` with single `reduce`. It should decrease `complexity`.  tsplay.dev/m0LXPm

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this... Note that I refactored the for loops.

```
// I did create this types for simulating your types
type Membership = { features : string[] }
type Observable<T> = any
function of<T>(someValue : T) : Observable<T>{}
interface MembershipFeatures { key1: string; key2: string; }


// My solution
type FoundRecord<T extends keyof MembershipFeatures> = { [key in T] : boolean}

// Function...
function getFeaturesFromMembership$<SelectedKey extends keyof MembershipFeatures>(
    membership$: Observable<Membership>,
    featureKeys: SelectedKey[],
    isPreview$: Observable<boolean> = of(false)
  ): Observable<FoundRecord<SelectedKey>> {
    return combineLatest([membership$, isPreview$])
      .pipe(
        map(([membership, isPreview]) => {
            const features: FoundRecord<SelectedKey> = {} as FoundRecord<SelectedKey>;
            for (const key of featureKeys) {
                if (!membership || isPreview) {
                    features[key] = true;
                } else {
                    features[key] = false;
                    features[key] = key in membership.features ? membership.features[key] : true
                }
            }

            return features;
        })
      );
  }
```