# Typescript: Dynamically check the second argument keys doesn't exists on first argument

Tags: typescript, type-constraints

I have a function that accept two arguments. Basically I want Typescript to check, the second argument must not contain key from the first argument. [TS Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gNyHKYQ0IMAOJ6IanQYgW%20AL5si%20APQzkAC2goAkorhRMCLBEzElyAOQlyEQ8gDWEAJ7IB%20lAHkAtqWQBXEmVK2w1nhAAdMgAsrYAju6c-CDIwDQANIroAO7EOM5wVvrx7NYgcK4ISQBGcDS6drFgBla29jUoFDBgyBqM7s4Q4IH4MO4gCDHE0QA8qAB8ABTNYNQAChokcGTjE0kMjApzyItQy6supONJxqQUhhMTAJTUAG7owHoERNogNOgUgWTojDMQLQ2wC2YGurHErCI0jkyAgAA8AkNKqgAMqwqBQdBQRTKUoQBBwdwVYjnFArKAQOCYWzw%20JgGhVBzIWZ2EoAK3xYHwkDo4yw6GmuBJpmohgAguZxEkhRwuLwYqKAEKGJImCiisXK5Dia5AA)

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
    
// here I hardcoded the 'title' key on the Omit utility type. My question is, how to make this dynamic, based on the key on the left argument.
function test<T>(left: Partial<T>, right: Partial<Omit<T, 'title'>>): void {
  console.log(left, right);
};
    
// expected TS error here, because title already exists on the left object
test<Todo>({ title: 'A' }, { description: 'B', title: 'AB' })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: let title = "Hello world";
let description = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
then use includes() function like so: description.includes(title)

Answer (score 0):

If one extra generic does not help, add another one :) This rule helps me every time when I have issues with generics.

See this example:

```js
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

const test = <
  Left extends Todo,
  PartialLeft extends Partial<Left>>
  (left: PartialLeft, right: Partial<Omit<Left, keyof PartialLeft>>) => { }

test({ title: 'A' }, { description: 'B', title: 'AB' }) // expected error

test({ description: 'A' }, { description: 'B', title: 'AB' }) // expected error
```

`Left` - infers first argument, which in turn, should extends `Todo`

`PartialLeft` - infers literal argument type

`Partial<Omit<Left, keyof PartialLeft>>` - means that second argument should omit all props from `PartialLeft` in `Left` generic argument.

`PartialLeft` plays key role in this function. This generic represents first argument.
If you want to learn more about type inference on function arguments you can take check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gNyHKYQ0IMAOJ6IanQYgW%20AL758CAXWKcwyALzIAPGwAyEGIogAPSCEw00WdABo2ABThQScMlp3J9h48ht3gD1U7AA%20fzYACgodak97R20wc2QGRgALMAjbKNUAeQBbUl8YuIBrCABPdBgPNO9onUCASmV-PGRJfEg6YNxiUgpqAHIAQV7muM6OLl5%20QWRegCFeuJJyKmn%20ueb6gHoNlz0eCARITBcoKHQoKTawDvZObmA%20YAE%20weGmsbuHp%20m5he7lgbW4k2230ewOECO0FOUCAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a way to make this dynamic with multiple type/interface (object literal with different keys). For example I have another `interface Task { name: string; time: string; }` . The idea if I do `test<Task>({ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B', { time: '10:10' })` it should throw an error without changing the function signature.

Comment: You should be aware that using explicit generic without corresponding value is unsafe. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431436/the-type-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-error/69432238#69432238 , this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596 and this https://catchts.com/infer-arguments