# The type could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote three functions with same type for each of them, let's see them.

```
const func: <T extends string, K extends number = any>(arg: T) => K = () => {
  return 1;
};

const anotherFunc = <T extends string, K extends number = any>(arg: T): K => {
  return 1;
};

function someFunc<T extends string, K extends number = any>(arg: T): K {
  return 1;
}
```

as you can see i defined `K` as number in all of them to returns a number in each of them, but a weird error occured that says:

this is for the first function:

```
Type '() => 1' is not assignable to type '<T extends string, K extends number = any>(arg: T) => K'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'K'.
    'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.
```

and this is for the last two functions:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'K'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'
```

i think the two errors have same point. why typescript can't realize that type?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a duplicate or not, but please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596)

Here is the simplified version of first example:

```js
const func: <K extends number>() => K = () => {
    return 1;
};
```

Now, try to call this function:`const result = func<42>(); // 42`. TS assumes, return type/value is `42`, but it is `1` in runtime.

Further more, `42 & { WAAAT: () => '?????' }` is a valid subtype of number.

```js
const result = func<42 & { WAAAT: () => '?????' }>();
result.WAAAT() // ?????
```

Above code compiles in TypeScript but throws a runtime error in runtime.
Please see the error message:

> `K` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `number`

`42 & { WAAAT: () => '?????' }` is a valid subtype of constraint `number`.

Hence, don't treat `extends` as `equal` operator.

Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) for more examples

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian Thanks buddy, i got it

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations.

- why do u have `args:T` if you never use it?
- why are you extending a primitive `string and number` and assigning an any type to `K`?
- your first `function` is wrong. Lets transformer to a classic function

```
const func: <T extends string, K extends number = any> function (args:T) {
  return K = function () { 
return 1;
}
}
```

Did you see the two errors ?

- to assign value we use `=` which you are not using in func look at anotherFunc for example
- you forgot to add the third error which Is

```
Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: `K = function` <--- this syntax is invalid