# Typescript Syntax for Type Inference based on kind

Tags: typescript, type-inference, union-types

I have an issue writing proper typescript syntax for strict infering where:

1. compiler properly reports on missing switch/case option
2. returned value matches input kind by type

```
type KindA = {kind:'a'};
type KindB = {kind:'b'};
type KindC = {kind:'c'};
type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;

function create<T extends AllKinds>(kind:AllKinds['kind']):T {
  switch(kind) {
    case "a": return {kind:'a'};
    case "b": return {kind:'b'};
    case "c": return {kind:'c'};
  }
}

create("a");
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glgOwCYEEoF4oG8DWikBcA5AIZEC+A3ALABQoks+AQhtnssQEYU33jR4yAMJtc+YgGNedBtBQAbBUKQBnNirQAfJslY6VwvnQBmAVwSTgcAPYIokgE4QSwCAB4AKlAgAPN8jqisr4qgB8ABQchMEqqgDaRNFEALoAlATeWHRQUKoA7nDAkgAWUfhp2Dm5DiSq0ABEJA0EUM7AZo724pykMrQ1tfVQDVwtbRAdXewSRDxU1bmSdY2S4+2d3dFS-bnkdPu0dE4ubhFNDWmUQA)

I wonder if this is possible with the latest Typescript.

With my other approach (i.e. `case "a": return {kind:'b'} as T;`) the returned value is not type checked to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

It is unsafe to return `T` in your case.

See why:

```js
type KindA = { kind: 'a' };
type KindB = { kind: 'b' };
type KindC = { kind: 'c' };
type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;

function create<T extends AllKinds>(kind: AllKinds['kind']): T {
  switch (kind) {
    case "a": return { kind: 'a' };
    case "b": return { kind: 'b' };
    case "c": return { kind: 'c' };
  }
}

const result = create<{ kind: 'a', WAAAT: () => {} }>("a")
result.WAAAT() // compiler but causes an error in runtime
```

Generic argument should in 90% of cases depend on input value.

See this example:

```js
type KindA = { kind: 'a' };
type KindB = { kind: 'b' };
type KindC = { kind: 'c' };
type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;


const builder = <Kind extends AllKinds['kind']>(kind: Kind) => ({ kind })

const result = builder("a"); // {kind: 'a' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glgOwCYEEoF4oG8oGtFIBcUA5AIYlQC%20A3ALABQoksBAQhtngcSQEaVajZtHjIAwpxz5kvAMaD6TcNBQAbNWKQBnTlrQAfVsg5Gt4pY0ZyA9gm3AofAK5w1SCACdOAHi1QIAA9gCGRddU0CbQBtEhkkEgBdAD4ACnjiLQBKDGSoVOkCaiyrBlt7R08IbWc1R0wXNw9PVIAiMlasmigAeh7sDNIKakYgA)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431436/the-type-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-error/69432238#69432238) answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596) answer and my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) for more context

> Do I get it right that witch current Typescript, one can not have both ?

The problem is not in `switch` statement but rather in explicit return type. Return type can't depend on a generic value which is not binded with function arguments.

In fact, it is possible to achieve waht you want:

```js
type KindA = { kind: 'a' };
type KindB = { kind: 'b' };
type KindC = { kind: 'c' };
type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;

function create<Kind extends AllKinds['kind']>(kind: Kind): Extract<AllKinds, { kind: Kind }>
function create(kind: AllKinds['kind']) {
    switch (kind) {
        case "a": return { kind: 'a' };
        case "b": return { kind: 'b' };
        case "c": return { kind: 'c' };
    }
}

const result1 = create("a") // KindA
const result2 = create("b") // KindB
const result3 = create("c") // KindC
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glgOwCYEEoF4oG8oGtFIBcUA5AIYlQC%20A3ALABQoksBAQhtngcSQEaVajZtHjIAwpxz5kvAMaD6TcNBQAbNWKQBnTlrQAfVsg5Gt4pYwBmAVwRzgcAPYIocgE4QywCAB4tUBAAHj7IuuqaBNoA2iQySCQAugB8ABTxxFoAlMQAoiHuZA6%20EVraADRcGcZI1MnWdg7Orh5ePuk8UKVRsfFJWdiMUMNQ2gDucMByABZQHcgDWEMjK3Jk2tAARGSbxJ7ANu6u0p3kissrw2sbUJt8u1D7h8fcsqQC1EqXI9dbcg9PI5VU4KT4XaiMKiMRhyFzaYCPCDaGxqYAARk4rW8EFS202AwA9ASaigYXCEZ5kaiAEyYzzY3H3QnErRsMkIeGIqnAADMdLaOM2-2ZNXE0IYQA)

As you might have noticed, I have used [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). It makes TS compiler less strict. In other words, provides a bit of unsafety but in the same time makes it more readable and infers return type.

AFAIK, function overloads behaves [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance). Hence, it is up to you which option is better

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do I get it right that witch current Typescript, one can not have both: 1. switch/case for kind at the same time as 2. return type check? Or can somehow both points from my original question matched?

Comment: @Yoz made an update

Comment: this version would let me do `case "a": return { kind: 'b' };`

Comment: This is why it is unsafe approach. Just like I said

Comment: Thanks, got, it... I will keep it open to see if anyone can come up with an idea to match both 1. and 2.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite descriptive.

```
Type '{ kind: "a"; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ kind: "a"; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AllKinds'.
```

This problem occurs even when you use a  simpler type constraint.

```js
function foo<T extends string>(): T {
  return 'foo';
}
```

Here we'd get the following error.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.
```

The problem is that we said that we'd return something of type `T`, but `T` is not the same type as `string`. Yes, the type `T` extends `string` but all that means is that `T` is a subtype of `string`. For example, the type `'bar'` is a subtype of `string`. Hence, we can instantiate `T` with `'bar'`. Hence, we'd expect the return value to be `'bar'` but the return value is `'foo'`.

The solution is to simply not use generics. If you want to return a `string` then just say that you're returning a `string`. Don't say that you're returning a value of some subtype `T` of `string`.

```js
function foo(): string {
  return 'foo';
}
```

Similarly, if you want to return a value of type `AllKinds` then just say that you're returning a value of type `AllKinds`. Don't say that you're returning a value of some subtype `T` of `AllKinds`.

```js
type KindA = {kind:'a'};
type KindB = {kind:'b'};
type KindC = {kind:'c'};
type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;

function create(kind:AllKinds['kind']): AllKinds {
  switch(kind) {
    case "a": return {kind:'a'};
    case "b": return {kind:'b'};
    case "c": return {kind:'c'};
  }
}

create("a");
```

---

**Edit:** You need dependent types to do what you want. TypeScript doesn't have dependent types. However, you can create a custom fold function that provides additional type safety.

```js
type Kind = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type KindA = { kind: 'a' };
type KindB = { kind: 'b' };
type KindC = { kind: 'c' };

type AllKinds = KindA | KindB | KindC;

function foldKind<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): (kind: Kind) => A | B | C {
  return function (kind: Kind): A | B | C {
    switch (kind) {
      case 'a': return a;
      case 'b': return b;
      case 'c': return c;
    }
  }
}

const create: (kind: Kind) => AllKinds = foldKind<KindA, KindB, KindC>(
  { kind: 'a' },
  { kind: 'b' },
  { kind: 'c' }
);
```

Now, you can only provide a value of `KindA` for `'a'`, a value of `KindB` for `'b'`, and a value of `KindC` for `'c'`. See the [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0glgOwCZQLxQOQEMNQD6YBGuBGAxhgNwCwAUHaJLIkgIJpQDeUA1iwFyYcUAL41ajaPGQAhDtz7JBGYqPGTmyAMLzeAzBTV0G4aKwA256UgDOHa+wLW5TllvF0AZgFcEZYHAA9ghQnoHmSNYAPKwANFAy8VoAfAAUWIJxUISCiVBkgloAlIKpikiC1kVoyVCOCfhQOpx0UFAAThDA3u0hPn4BwVBl+lWZjS5NXK1tUDYA7nDAZAAWw+XVLbSzs2RYNtDYGIKd3b1QWOI7bXsHRMcdXT0hhFfXt4cUJ0-nZG9tIhmgNowLoZGCNmA+U6WGAEFK5UqLGqqFqFisLDs6DCEWiDnizgJbjSMwU+iOolipL0SnulOpiIMuGBRXEQA) for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do I get it right that witch current Typescript, one can not have both: 1. switch/case for kind at the same time as 2. return type check? Or can somehow both points from my original question matched?

Comment: You can have both, as is shown in my answer above. I don't know why you're trying to shoehorn in a generic type though.

Comment: with the proposed syntax, one can do `case "a": return {kind:'b'};` - means compiler is not guarding as I would like it to. (see my point 2)

Comment: You need dependent types to do what you want. TypeScript doesn't have dependent types. However, you can create a custom fold function that provides additional type safety. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Aadit. Still seem not generic enough (Imagine I have 10+, 100+ kinds) and also `create("a")` returns AllKind instead of KindA. I understand this is a current limitation of the language so I have created a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46236 .