# TypeScript: 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | string[]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to define a function that takes either a string or an array of strings and does something with them, e.g. uppercasing them.

If the function takes a string, it should return a string. And, if it takes an array of strings, it should return an array of strings.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
const uppercase = <Params extends string | string[]>(params: Params): Params => {
  if (typeof params === "string") {
    return params.toUpperCase(); // ERROR: 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Params', but 'Params' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | string[]'.
  }

  return params.map(param => param.toUpperCase()); // ERROR: 'string[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Params', but 'Params' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | string[]'
}
```

How would you fix this?

Comment: What happens if using the type union directly (instead of using/defining Params)? The *”different subtype of”* seems like interesting wording.

Comment: It won't express my intent since it would allow you to pass a `string` and return a `string[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do it, you should overload your function:

```js
const toUppercase = (str: string) => str.toUpperCase();

function uppercase(params: string[]): string[]
function uppercase(params: string): string
function uppercase<Params extends string | string[]>(params: Params) {
  return typeof params === "string" ? toUppercase(params) : params.map(toUppercase)

}

const str = uppercase('hello') // string
const arr = uppercase(['hello']) // string[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIFUAOSCmAnYBDCqYF4YAKadALhlIEswBzASgID5Kp0A6eZNdAYR1RF6AbgBQogGYBXMMChVwMKSgzZcRJFnRYAthArU6AbQC69A2xq1TkmXIVglKzAI1bd%201uivmvV27Lyiso8aqgAPAAK7nowqAAeUKhgACYQfnQwAD4Z1iZMbtp6FNFFEIwA3qIwMOioUFLojlAAnmggEjCaZQT4hABEhrT9MAD8cIjOYYUejBTdHuw6WEhEXFMC9OIAvuKgkLCkBE6hrgDkABaoADbXIGeMAPSPuaL70DBa6Mchqq5GlxudzOZhgz1ypiAA)

If you are interested in more sophisticated typings, consider this example:

```js
const toUppercase = <Str extends string>(str: Str) => str.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Str>;

type TupleUppercase<
  T extends string[],
  Accumulator extends string[] = []
  > =
  (T extends []
    ? Accumulator
    : (T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
      ? (Head extends string
        ? (Tail extends string[]
          ? TupleUppercase<Tail, [...Accumulator, Uppercase<Head>]>
          : never)
        : never)
      : never)
  )


function uppercase<Param extends string, Params extends Param[]>(params: [...Params]): TupleUppercase<Params>
function uppercase<Param extends string>(params: Param): Uppercase<Param>
function uppercase<Params extends string | string[]>(params: Params) {
  return typeof params === "string" ? toUppercase(params) : params.map(toUppercase)

}

const str = uppercase('hello') // "HELLO"
const arr = uppercase(['hello', 'world']) // ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIFUAOSCmAnYBDCqYF4YAeAZSnRlQA8pUwATCGadASzAHMA%20AChYC4YZdAEoCXZuQB08ZGnQBhHKh5icMORmy5S5LgG4AUIagBPNDAAqAVyQAbVJszKihmFco06jSW04BtAF0AGjcYAEFgYGsAW2s7LHgKaloGJhZ2DiCCGCCwiXwwnktPVJ8893cAfgio2PjEkHQw90Fi0u8mf3YAMwwYAAlULHpgmCkJ3v7LLFY7QJbKmp4hkY6030zFyphlmbn1nwyAhZ2z3atbBydtVCJ9uzH-CalI6LiEpLGbl1X6LkCXG2Z0EYFQADcMCJga0YGDIaJgaCIVCwtDjD1rGBgFBWOAYLZ5LciAAFLDoLAxQ7pciZMZkikxJgpTowBmUoK8JDkykQQTPCbspmBESCGz2RwoLQuIUQIGY7G4-GE6U6IXUzacLk8pmCIWijRS5xqnXyrE4vFgAlG4myjXHDgwAA%20mqygJ43MZfLZOogYgA3mF0KgoNZ0FazGgQD0YJ7eQR8IQAEQOpMXWQ25Qe31iQRxplSGJYJA8DNE5TogC%20xlAkFgLByKuNKgA5AALVB2OwgFtiAD0fZgSYGAFEADJjgDyScMtegMHJFEITduPH87c73ZbYxbAHcmnZ6C2RTAB7lh%20Op0mxkmAOqTgBKY4AIknAkA)

Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

P.S. You are not allowed to return generic `Params` in your implementation because it is considered unsafe behavior. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596) and/or my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints)

Consider this **UNSAFE** example:

```js
const toUppercase = (str: string) => str.toUpperCase();

function uppercase<Params extends string | string[]>(params: Params): Params {
  return typeof params === "string" ? toUppercase(params) : params.map(toUppercase)
}

uppercase('hello') // 'hello' but 'HELLO' in runtime
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! Could you remove `Params` in the implementation and simply have `function uppercase(params: string | string[]) { ... }`?

Comment: You can remove `Params` from the first implementation but not from the second. In order to infer argument you should provide generic parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you will allow casting, for me the errors went away when I added casting on return values

```
const uppercase = <Params extends string | string[]>(params: Params): Params => {
    if (typeof params === "string") {
      return params.toUpperCase() as Params; 
    }
  
    return params.map(param => param.toUpperCase()) as Params; 
  }
```

---

Edit

You check the type with an *if*. Which allows you to know for sure: the object return is the same type as the argument. But TS doesn't know that. That [string returned *implies* string received].

I think you can accomplish similar to what you want with class generics.

```
const uppercase = <Type extends string|string[]>(params: Type, converter: UpperCaser<Type>) => {
    return converter.toUpperCase(params);
}

abstract class UpperCaser<Param> {
    abstract toUpperCase(param: Param): Param;
}

class StringArray extends UpperCaser<string[]> {
    toUpperCase(stringArray: string[]): string[] {
        return stringArray.map(param => param.toUpperCase());
    }
}

class StringObj extends UpperCaser<string> {
    toUpperCase(string: string): string {
        return string.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

It doesn't need to be precisely this approach; adjust to your liking.

Comment: With this approach, you could change `return params.toUpperCase() as Params;` to `return [params.toUpperCase()] as Params;` and TypeScript will be happy. I'd like TypeScript to complain if it knows that `params` is `string` but the return type is `string[]`, or vice versa.

Comment: Got it. This help?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Let's take a look at the critical part of each error message:

> 'Params' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | string[]'

What is an example where `Params` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `string | string[]`?

```
const foo = 'foo';

uppercase(foo);
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwQUwE7AIYWTAvDAHgAUNUMBbCGZADymTABMrpUBLMAcxgB8ZWOnANoBdAHwAKBKQoQAXDBJlKASgVLZeMTADeAKBgw2AMxgSoATxQhT05VVyOYAIgFdnK3QcMxUyKHCoYDB2sgB0UCAAqkhoAMJYyBIqANwwAPTpMACiAEq5APK5CgDkbpwlRlRYEGycYBgARgA2OJEwUAAWOKCQUGQcsDYdVjglGpQlADQwjXCw4zKTMKBwzYyzOBzQGGBQbBj0GwDubF0wGDCMJsZoDLAQcI2WKDDDvawYgzBl-YK8-D+XFEJTC3gAvnpvH4AkEQksIGFyBgEFIllp4coItFYqgEthkqkMlk8oVij9yiCqhcILV6k1Wh0QB1uitwJ9vsMXmMJhBprN5j9eZVVutNkY+rt9odkCczp0Llcbnc9vwnty3qYPv0vqrfuwuADKSISnpIXptTBjCBmfgStaQCUUlDECh0IkJA7UkA)

If you hover over the declaration for the `foo` variable, you'll see it has the following type:

```
const foo: 'foo'
```

And then if you hover over the call to `uppercase`, you'll see it has the following type:

```
const uppercase: <"foo">(params: "foo") => "foo"
```

Type `'foo'` extends `string` so it satisfies the generic constraint. However your function's return type is now `'foo'` while `toUpperCase` returns `string`. While type `'foo'` is type `string`, not all `string`s are `'foo'`s.

Similarly if you, say, pass a tuple:

```
const tuple: ['foo'] = ['foo'];

uppercase(tuple)
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwQUwE7AIYWTAvDAHgAUNUMBbCGZADymTABMrpUBLMAcxgB8ZWOnANoBdAHwAKBKQoQAXDBJlKASgVLZeMTADeAKBgw2AMxgSoATxQhT05VVyOYAIgFdnK3QcMxUyKHCoYDB2sgB0UCAAqkhoAMJYyBIqANwwAPTpMACiAEq5APK5CgDkbpwlRlRYEGycYBgARgA2OJEwUAAWOKCQUGQcsDYdVjglGpQlADQwjXCw4zKTMKBwzYyzOBzQGGBQbBj0GwDubF0wGDCMJsZoDLAQcI2WKDDDvawYgzBl-YK8-D+XFEJTC3gAvnpvH4AkEQksIGFyBgEFIllp4coItFYqgEthkqkMlk8oVij9yiCqhcILV6k1Wh0QB1uitwJ9vsMXmMJhBprN5j9eZVVutNkY+rt9odkCczp0Llcbnc9vwnty3qYPv0vqrfuwuADKSISnpIXptTBjCAQAohCVrSASiI8DB7Y7nSkoYgUOhEhJHakgA)

The type for `uppercase` will become:

```
const uppercase: <["foo"]>(params: ["foo"]) => ["foo"]
```

however `map` returns `string[]`. While type `['foo']` is type `string[]`, not all `string[]`s are `['foo']`s.

In both cases you don't want the constrained type.

## (Partial) Solution

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to ensure the correct return type is paired with the correct argument type:

```
function uppercase(params: string): string;
function uppercase(params: string[]): string[];
function uppercase(params: string | string[]): string | string[] {
  if (typeof params === "string") {
    return params.toUpperCase();
  }

  return params.map(param => param.toUpperCase());
}
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADigpgJwgQwM7oAUKOmOAtngFyJ5SYxgDmAlDXQ8wNwBQoksBMjRZcBYqQrVa9RkwDaAXTYzOCxb37R4SVBmz4iJMpXazmiAD6q5SlRzlWbzJYgDePRIhjBEhKACeGHC+xlKIALxRiABEDswxLO6eXoiY6FAgmEhhlAB0UHAAqiKYAMKGhCy8XgC+PCnpmdmIuXh55DgoEiaRAHytkuQFxaUV4izVPPU8EAh0iMBwcDTyAORLcGuKkYjrm9u8s-NQwvoAYsu7eqKVm9VAA)

I understand that you want your function return implementation to be type checked as well (ie you don't want it to be possible to return an array when a string is the argument and vice versa) however I don't believe it is possible<sup>[[reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13225)]</sup>, at least with overloads and without significant changes – I see there's an answer that uses classes. While the solution I've noted here does not do checks on the implementation, it does do checks on the call site, which is some value:

```
const uppercaseString = uppercase('foo');
const uppercaseArray = uppercase(['foo']);

// Attempt to call Array.prototype.map on a string
uppercaseString.map();
                ^^^
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.

// Attempt to call String.prototype.substring on an array
uppercaseArray.substring();
               ^^^^^^^^^
Property 'substring' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=17#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADigpgJwgQwM7oAUKOmOAtngFyJ5SYxgDmAlDXQ8wNwBQoksBMjRZcBYqQrVa9RkwDaAXTYzOCxb37R4SVBmz4iJMpXazmiAD6q5SlRzlWbzJYgDePRIhjBEhKACeGHC+xlKIALxRiABEDswxLO6eXoiY6FAgmEhhlAB0UHAAqiKYAMKGhCy8XgC+PCnpmdmIuXh55DgoEiaRAHytkuQFxaUV4izVPPU8EAh0wvpi6ADK5kyRi6KVAOTAcHA7U3NgC3rbBACCmGQBm+cG4vJ7BzvKvDwPy2tqHV1VNVSQOBqQAeuCeAAFTBwfSBRA7TooHaIAAmcHQeEQYDgUEQ6AAHjAFkJAhgEfEmDs8g1PqVltdbnk8CAAEaUgEpEHc8G8vlQmFwu47Fns9Yo9GY7G4-FEklIMnoCnrJTUrnckFAA)

Answer (score 0):

This people like to complicate them selfs. There are many ways of fix ing this but the easiest

```
if (typeof (param as string)==="string") {
```

or another one would be

```
if (Array.isArray(param)) {}
```

Instead of comparing if it is an string  check if it is an array